# How can I resolve a collation error in my DB migration?

Tags: mysql, cleardb

I am trying to migrate my db from localhost onto cleardb. Upon importing my db onto cleardb I am getting the error Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'. I have no idea what a collation is, nor can I find anything online about what collation's cleardb accepts. I'm guessing it has something to do with the character set that is being submitted.

What are my option on how to fix this?

thanks

Comment: set charset="utf8" and collation="utf8_general_ci" in config/database.php of MySQL array

Answer (score 1):

for collation error, you need to follow the following steps

1, go to config/database.php file
2, set charset="utf8" and collation="utf8_general_ci"

final MySQL array show like below

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```